# jQuery profile page > Overlay

Tags: jquery, overlay

I am looking to create a profile page. It will have use an unordered list with `li`'s floating left in a column view. Each `li` will represent a profile picture (leading to an overlay).

I want to click on a profile picture and show it using jQuery, an HTML article. This article will be their profile page. I am able to create the CSS3 and HTML. But how do I call the image and their information to the article (profile template)?

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 currently on a PHP basic website (locally) using MAMP on an iMac. I could use a database, but would prefer to use a JavaScript file to store the information.

Required profile info:

- Image
- Name
- Title
- Mob No
- Work No
- EMAIL
- Quote Title
- Blockquote

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **external files** (.json, .xml, even .txt) to store your data :

1. Stock the information into an XML / JSON file,
2. Then retrieve the fields by parsing your XML / JSON into an object in JS
3. Populate your HTML fields with JS

No database, but not really handy, as you'll have to parse the entire file to retrieve field(s).

Answer (score 0):

1. use ajax to do a request to a php file, sending the id of the picture you clicked
2. grab all the information you need from the database with a query
3. wrap it all up in a JSON
4. send it back to the js file
5. decode it into an array
6. use the js array to populate the html with all the profile information

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
//on click element, get id from element
$.ajax({
    url: "getProfileInfo.php",
    data: {id : id},
    success: function(data) {
        // decode data to get your js array object
        // step 6
    }
});
```

If you get into trouble you can always google about jquery ajax, also here's a simple example link
http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/